# Getting "Template is missing" error when attempting to render js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails, and I'm having an issue where I can't render a .js.erb file. I think the root of the issue is that Rails' internal routing mechanism expects me to name and configure my files just so, but I'm missing one or two pieces, and I'm not sure how to look for what needs to be fixed.

I have an HTML view with a link to a controller action:

```
<%# snip %>
<div id="holding_issues_list">
  <%= link_to "Show issues on hold", {
      :action => "show_user_issues",
      :controller => "support",
      :issue_type => "holding",
      :user_id => @user.id },
    :remote => true %>
</div>
<%# snip %>
```

I think (but I'm not sure) that `:remote => true` causes the link to make an AJAX call.

This is the corresponding controller action in the controller `app/controllers/support_controller.rb`:

```
def show_user_issues
  @target_div = params[:target_div] || "holding_issues_list"
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  issue_type = params[:issue_type]

  #snip - set the value of @issues
end
```

I want this file, named `show_user_issues.js.erb` and placed in `app/views/support`, to be rendered when the controller exits:

```
$("#<%= @target_div %>").show();
alert('test');
$("#<%= @target_div %>").html(
  "<%= escape_javascript render :partial => '_show_user_issues', :locals => {:target_div => @target_div, :issues => @issues} %>");
```

This is `app/views/support/_show_user_issues.html.erb`, the partial I want `show_user_issues.js.erb` to render:

```
<% for issue in @active_issues %>
  <div id="issue_<%= issue.id %>_display">
      <%= render :partial => 'show_issue_mini', :locals => {:issue => issue} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try clicking the link in my original HTML view, nothing happens. When I open it up in a new tab, I get this error message:

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template support/show_user_issues,
>   application/show_user_issues with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :handlers=>[:builder, :erb], :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/<>/app/views" *
>   "/home/<>/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"

The `alert('test')` that I put into `show_user_issues.js.erb` doesn't show up, so I *think* that Rails is getting hung up on rendering that file - that is, the routing mechanism can't find it. How can I correct this issue?

P.S. I double-checked that I put in all the file names exactly as they are in the code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller action to handle the type of request.

```
def show_user_issues
  @target_div = params[:target_div] || "holding_issues_list"
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  issue_type = params[:issue_type]

  #snip - set the value of @issues

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

This will check the format of the request which is `.js` in case of `:remote => true`. So it will handle it by rendering the `show_user_issues.js.erb` file.

Answer (score 2):

A couple other problems that I ran into after applying Manoj Monga's answer that I suspect other new Rails devs might run into:

---

In `show_user_issues.js.erb`, I had

```
[...].html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => '_show_user_issues',[...]
```

The underscore before `'_show_user_issues'` caused the ERB builder to fail. It should have just been `'show_user_issues'`.

---

In `_show_user_issues.html.erb`, I had

```
<% for issue in @active_issues %>
```

If you look closely at `show_user_issues.js.erb`, though, I named the variable `@issues`, not `@active_issues`:

```
[...]:locals => {:target_div => @target_div, :issues => @issues}[...]
```

So I changed the line in the HTML partial to

```
<% for issue in @issues %>
```

After these last couple changes, the new functionality I was adding worked as expected.

Comment: I guess, I overlooked those points after I saw you were missing the format part. :)

Comment: @ManojMonga That's all right. The format.js part was the biggest thing I was missing - after that, I was able to figure the rest out pretty quickly. I just want to leave this here in case anyone has similar problems in the future. Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: The main purpose of this forum is to help everyone who come across it, hence you get +1 on this answer ;) BTW you are welcome :)